# How do I use C# to encrypt/decrypt data where the private key is on a smartcard, hardware security module, TPM chip etc

Tags: appsec, cryptography, key-management, .net, smartcard

Is anyone aware of a C# code sample to interact with smartcard, hardware security module, TPM chips (etc), that will allow me to encrypt and decrypt data?

My goal is to allow my application to support a variety of key stores, and should the administrator decide they want the Private key to reside on those devices, I want to be able to support that.

Is there a consistent, or universal way to access these devices?  Is there a way through C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Windows world, cryptography with special hardware goes through the "Cryptographic Service Providers" (CSP). A CSP is a module registered in the OS, which offers access to such a kind of hardware.

From C#, you can look at [RSACryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s575f7e2.aspx), which can be created with some parameters which designate a specific CSP.

The non-Windows world tends to use [PKCS#11](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2133) for that. Google finds some software packages which can apparently use a PKCS#11 DLL (i.e. the driver for the crypto hardware) from C#; e.g. [pkcs11.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pkcs11net/) and [NCryptoki](http://www.ncryptoki.com/) (the former seems to be open source, not the latter).

Comment: +1. In other words - you need the "driver" for the specific hardware. One tip - make sure to look at the `CSPParameters` class, too...

Comment: Using C# on non-Windows is not a nice idea anyway. If your application is in fact a user-facing application (meaning you're more interested in accessing a smart card rather than a HSM) you're better off with CryptoAPI than PKCS#11, as CryproAPI layer takes better care of usability issues than PKCS#11 (think: certificate selection, PIN entry etc) While it is generally possible to have "universal" crypto interfaces, I suggest to consider user experience and usability as well. Choose usability and implementation complexity over portability and ease of coding.

Comment: Related: Should I use Microsoft's RSA CSP or AES CSP for best interoperability? http://security.stackexchange.com/q/15626/396